# Indexing firebase objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

How am I able to create an index for the object data that I am passing into Firebase?

I am using the `.$add` function in the AngularFire library to push the data. This is the filter and controller that I am using:

```
angular.module('bestDay', ["firebase"]).factory("GreatService", ["$firebase", function($firebase) {
    var ref = new Firebase("https://quickjournal.firebaseIO.com/");
    return $firebase(ref);
}])
.controller("bdctrl", ["$scope", "GreatService",
    function($scope, greatService) {
        $scope.theval = "Val " + Math.round(Math.random()*101);
        $scope.daylist = greatService;
        $scope.addDayGood = function() {
            $scope.daylist.$add({
                desc: $scope.newDay.desc,
                date: $scope.newDay.date,
                value: $scope.theval
            });
            $scope.newDay.desc = "";
            $scope.newDay.date = "";
        };
    }
]);
```

As you can see, I was attempting to use a unique value when passing the objects in, but it was only generating the same number every time (13). If it isn't apparent, I am semi-new to programming.

I would also like to be able to write a function that will remove the data by that index. Since I am unable to conquer the prior task, I may need assistance in doing this as well.
I am writing my code with the angularjs library.

I have combed through the firebase and angularfire library documentation with no results. If you could point me to a URL with the documentation on this, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you say "index", do you mean "unique id"? Because in that case you should simply use the `push` function to have Firebase generate an id for your new data. See https://www.firebase.com/docs/javascript/firebase/push.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase should do the indexing, as this makes it easier if you have more than one user accessing the same data.

Relevant to your question, you should look up https://www.firebase.com/docs/ordered-data.html for working with lists in firebase.

More the point, the `push()` function provided makes for easy chronological sorting, and if you need more complex sorting you can look at the `setWithPriority()` function.

```
angular.module('bestDay', ["firebase"])
.controller("bdctrl", ['$scope', '$firebase',
    function($scope,$firebase) {
        var daysRef = new Firebase("https://quickjournal.firebaseIO.com/daylist/");
        $scope.dayList = $firebase(daysRef);
        $scope.dayLocationInFirebase = daysRef.push();
        $scope.addDayGood = function(){
                              // Setdata to the generated location
                              $scope.dayLocationInFirebase.set({
                                                 desc: $scope.newDay.desc,
                                                 date: $scope.newDay.date
                                             });

                              //holds reference to location the object was pushed to, for direct manipulation of the value. Pass it to the scope or an array if you need it for later
                              var pushedName = $scope.dayLocationInFirebase.name();
                               alert(pushedName);
                              $scope.newDay.desc = "";
                              $scope.newDay.date = "";
                          }


    }
]);
```

Comment: This code is not working. I am getting an error on my .push() method:

TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'push'

Is this because of how my libraries are ordered? In the <head> tags I pass in angularjs, then firebase.js, then angularfire, then my javascript script.js file.

Here is the repo if you would like to see the full code:

[Repo](https://github.com/JordanFarnworth/BestDay)

Comment: I edited the code from your git repo, and this one works. Watch out for caps.

The push() function takes the firebase reference. In the previous(and wrong) example, I did it to the returned objects.